# how to get a list of pvalues?

Tags: r

I performed a wilcox test and now I want to extract the p.value in to a list or matrix.

```
DF <- data.frame(A1=sample(1:9, 10, T),
                     A2=sample(1:9, 10, T),
                     A3=sample(1:9, 10, T),
                     B1=sample(1:9, 10, T),
                     B2=sample(1:9, 10, T),
                     B3=sample(1:9, 10, T))


sampA <- DF[,grep('A', names(DF))]  # Sample with columns A
sampB <- DF[,grep('B', names(DF))]  # Sample with columns B


lapply(1:nrow(DF), function(i){
  wilcox.test(as.numeric(sampA[i,]), as.numeric(sampB[i,]), exact=FALSE )
})
```

The result of my wilcox test for each rows looks like this:
I wanna know how i can get the p.value in a list or a matrix to export to a excel file?
    [[1]]

```
    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  as.numeric(sampA[i, ]) and as.numeric(sampB[i, ]) 
W = 3, p-value = 0.6579
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0 


[[2]]

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  as.numeric(sampA[i, ]) and as.numeric(sampB[i, ]) 
W = 0, p-value = 0.0722
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0 


[[3]]

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  as.numeric(sampA[i, ]) and as.numeric(sampB[i, ]) 
W = 6, p-value = 0.6579
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Answer (score 11):

Just add `$p.value` to extract your p.value from your `wilcox.test` object :

```
lapply(1:nrow(DF), function(i){
  wilcox.test(as.numeric(sampA[i,]), as.numeric(sampB[i,]), exact=FALSE )$p.value
})
```

Which gives :

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 0.8247781

[[4]]
[1] 0.8247781
```

By using `sapply` instead of  `lapply` you would get a vector instead of a list, which could be easier to manipulate.

```
sapply(1:nrow(DF), function(i){
  wilcox.test(as.numeric(sampA[i,]), as.numeric(sampB[i,]), exact=FALSE )$p.value
}) 

# [1] 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.8247781 0.8247781 0.0765225 0.8247781 1.0000000
# [8] 0.8247781 0.2682859 0.0765225
```

Comment: +1 for beating me to the punch by ~ 60 seconds (and having the same thought regarding `sapply` obviously!) :-)

Answer (score 4):

Use `sapply` and reference the p.value name...

```
sapply(1:nrow(DF), function(i){wilcox.test(as.numeric(sampA[i,]), as.numeric(sampB[i,]), exact=FALSE )$p.value})

#[1] 0.8247781 0.0765225 0.8247781 1.0000000 0.2682859 0.6625206 1.0000000
#[8] 0.1211833 0.5065552 0.8247781
```

This will return a vector rather than a list (I usually find vectors to be easier to handle, e.g. because you can't index a list using `mylist[[1:5]]`, but you can do `myvector[1:5]`, but that's personal preference